# speed up this matlab code?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

Is there a good way to speed up this block of matlab code (`n` in particular, can be large) using matrix operations, or anything?  Over 1/4 of my execution time is in this small block of code.

```
% Get the bin indexes that we will place the network in
bins = [];
for n=low_freq:0.5:high_freq;
    bins = [bins, (n-spec_start)/spec_bin_size+1];
end
```

Test code:

```
spec_start=2400
spec_bin_size=0.5
low_freq = 2437
high_freq=2438

bins = [];
for n=low_freq:0.5:high_freq;
    bins = [bins, (n-spec_start)/spec_bin_size+1];
end

bins  % 75 76 77

bins = [];
bins = (low_freq:0.5:high_freq - spec_start)./spec_bin_size + 1;

bins  % empty?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip the loop:

```
bins = ((low_freq:0.5:high_freq) - spec_start)./spec_bin_size + 1;
```

In situations where you can't do vectorized calculations as above, you should at least [preallocate the output array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html#f8-793781)

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Sorry for making you waste your time.

Comment: hmmmm, I think something is slightly off.  I think the result of this script should be 75,76,77 .. but I get an empty matrix from your code.  Test code included in edit'ed question.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: a-ha, just a little adjustment to parens: ((low_freq:0.5:high_freq) - spec_start)./spec_bin_size + 1

Comment: missing square brackets.  how about this:([low_freq:0.5:high_freq] - spec_start)./spec_bin_size + 1